# Navigation Bar Title not appearing in simulator SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm not sure if Xcode has a bug or if I'm wrong, but I have mi `Home()` view which has a TabView, this tab view allow me to navigate to differences views, while I was coding my `SettingsView()` I notice than in canvas I can see the NavigationBarTitle, but then I run simulator, the title don't appear.

[Home() View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2MNl.png)

```
struct Home: View {
    
    @State var tabPredeterminado:Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabPredeterminado) {
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                    Text("Settings")
                }.tag(3)
            
                
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

[SettingsView()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH3TU.png)

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {...}
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
        }
    }
}
```

[Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDg4j.png)

Comment: Always supply code as text, _never_ as images. Please [edit] your question

Comment: Done! I was using images due to I thought it was a lot of text haha

Comment: Thank you. Can you please create a [mcve], that anyone trying to help you can compile and run?

Comment: What is the ContentView ? Did you wrongly add a navigation view or stack in it ?

Comment: `TabView` should always be at the very top, I am assuming your `ContentView` has a `NavigationStack` or `NavigationView`, that is incorrect. Each tab can have one.

Comment: I want to leave more code in this question, but I can't, so, here a leave my iCloud [link](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0d3yq4cNf368g8foOedSp61Kw#Pumping_Fitness) so you can download my project.